# How do I use constructor overloading to create 2 separate "warehouses"?

Tags: c#

For my assignment in class this week, we are to overload the "warehouse constructor". The first step was to set up the warehouse class with 0 radios, computers, and televisions with a constructor. There should also be buttons to add to the stock of each item. The starting inventory for all should be 0. I am unsure if I performed this correctly.

Then we have to overload that constructor and make a warehouse with pre-assigned numbers. I did this but I am getting 0 for my number of Radios when calling my first warehouse...

I am very confused on this topic and was looking to see if someone could help explain better what my problem is? It'd be much appreciated.

Here is my warehouse class:

```
class warehouse
    {
        private static int radios, televisions, computers;

        public warehouse (int r, int t, int c)
        {
            r = Radios;
            t = Televisions;
            c = Computers;
        }

        public warehouse()
        {
            radios = 5;
            televisions = 5;
            computers = 5;
        }

        warehouse one = new warehouse(5, 6, 5);
        warehouse two = new warehouse();

        public static int Radios
        {
            get
            {
                return radios;
            }

            set
            {
                radios = value;
            }
        }

        public static int Televisions
        {
            get
            {
                return televisions;
            }

            set
            {
                televisions = value;
            }
        }

        public static int Computers
        {
            get
            {
                return computers;
            }

            set
            {
                computers = value;
            }
        }



    }
}
```

Then what follows is my form for displaying the warehouse.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private static int R, C, T;

        public static int R1
        {
            get
            {
                return R;
            }

            set
            {
                R = value;
            }
        }

        public static int C1
        {
            get
            {
                return C;
            }

            set
            {
                C = value;
            }
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = warehouse.Radios.ToString();
        }

        public static int T1
        {
            get
            {
                return T;
            }

            set
            {
                T = value;
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I am intending to display each item in the warehouse in a separate TextBox and then have buttons below to add 1 to the stock at the press of each button.

As of now, only a zero is popping up when I press to display the warehouse.

Comment: First thing to fix: your fields and properties are all static. That's very odd when you're initializing them in a constructor. Second thing to fix - your assignments in the constructor are the wrong way round... you're assigning *to* the parameters *from* the properties. Next: learn about automatically implemented properties, so that each of your 12-line properties can be implemented in a single line...

Comment: also I think you want to create the warehouse objects in the form test code rather than inside the warehouse (unless they store matryoshka dolls, maybe)

Answer (score 0):

In this part...

```
    public warehouse (int r, int t, int c)
    {
        r = Radios;
        t = Televisions;
        c = Computers;
    }
```

... you are putting the parameters on the left of the assignment and the properties to the right. That means you overwrite the arguments with the property values (which are initialized with their default values of 0). You are not setting any property. You have to do it the other way round: set the properties from the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

first thing you need to do is without creating the object,can't override the values of class members.here,you should create object for your warehouse class at inside **Form1** class then every thing will be works fine.

```
 public warehouse (int r, int t, int c)
{
    r = Radios;
    t = Televisions;
    c = Computers;
}
```

here you are assigning values in wrong way i thought.should assign values to the your properties rather than to the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Warehouse class:

```
class Warehouse
{
    private int radios, televisions, computers;

    public int Radios
    {
        get { return radios; }
        set { radios = value; }
    }

    public int Televisions
    {
        get { return televisions; }
        set { televisions = value; }
    }

    public int Computers
    {
        get { return computers; }
        set { computers = value; }
    }

    public Warehouse(int radios, int televisions, int computers)
    {
        this.radios = radios;
        this.televisions = televisions;
        this.computers = computers;
    }

    public Warehouse() : this(5, 5, 5) { }
}
```

Here, the fields and properties are non-static (instance members). Static members are maintained for the class globally, meaning there will be only a single copy, so you can't have multiple warehouses. Instance members are maintained as separate copies for each instance (each object) so you can maintain multiple warehouses.

If you want, you can define the properties as auto-implemented properties.

Example Form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Warehouse warehouse1;
    private Warehouse warehouse2;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        warehouse1 = new Warehouse();
        warehouse2 = new Warehouse(6, 7, 8);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = warehouse1.Radios.ToString();
        textBox2.Text = warehouse1.Televisions.ToString();
        textBox3.Text = warehouse1.Computers.ToString();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = warehouse2.Radios.ToString();
        textBox2.Text = warehouse2.Televisions.ToString();
        textBox3.Text = warehouse2.Computers.ToString();
    }
}
```

Here, when you click on button1, the details of warehouse1 will be shown in the textboxes, and warehouse2 for button2...